# Reroute requests for rear camera to front camera

Tags: camera, hardware, front-camera

My rear camera doesn't work (very well) and so I can't scan the QR Code which is needed to access WhatsApp web.

There are no options within WhatsApp to change which camera to use or anything like that, so I'd like to re-route requests for the rear camera to the front camera.

Is that possible?

---

Moto G4 running Android 7.0

Comment: Try this [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=appinventor.ai_brandonbartlett18.StartFrontCamera)

Comment: Doesn't open the front camera on my device.